I can't redeem my tokenset
Hello Ethereum developers, i am sorry for sending a message here because my issue is on polygon chain and I don't know if I can drop it here, Chatgpt told me to try it out and maybe I will get help.
Years ago, i created a Tokenset on polygonchain and named it RVOP, I then supplied some erc20 tokens to my tokenset all on the tokenset UI but fastforward to today, the tokenset UI isn't functional anymore and I cant redeem my tokenset, I checked online and tried redeeming manually using the set debt issuance module but I have had no luck, please I do not know what to do anymore, this money is $250 and it means alot to me at this point as I have currently lost my job, if anyone can help me so I can redeem my tokenset and get back the erc20 tokens that I supplied, I will appreciate it, I know nothing about smart contracts and I don't know what to do, I will leave details of the tokenset and the transaction error I got, thank you ethereum devs.
RVOP Tokenset token ADDRESS: 0x0a017EF551274eC8F7C0bbeBf9f7297eD8Bc7a7a
Last txid: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x78351020b06d5758db3c8af8b6abdc107b36c8199d3e6a2968f04b406ecc61a5

I found this webpage saved on ipfs, are you able to use it? https://bafybeies5y255t7unu2ahkijgihzuyie6iqyqsbk66l5phtfvca4bikbvq.ipfs.dweb.link/#/explore?show=uncategorized

I also looked at the contract. I think you are correct calling the redeem function, maybe try using a smaller amount (_quantity) cause there are some fees

Managed to manually redeem my Tokenset of SetProtocolv2 this way:
1. Go to https://polygonscan.com/address/0x38E5462BBE6A72F79606c1A0007468aA4334A92b#writeContract#F3
2. Connect wallet
3. redeem()
_setToken: Your SetToken Contract Adress
_quantity: Your Token Quanitity plus the following zeros -> 26 Tokens was
26000000000000000000 for me
_to: The Adress where you have your SetToken Tokens that wants to redeem them
4. Click "Write"
Hope this helps you recover your funds 

This only is for polygon settokens tho, eth layer 1 would have a different adress of contract
